# Log Out message box appear twice when click on logout button

Tags: vb.net, messagebox

So I would like to perform a confirmation before i close the application or logout the application by clicking the logout button or just click to close the application. If i directly close the application then the message box just appear once. However when i use the logout button then the message box appear twice.

So the coding is basically look like this:

```
Private Sub btnLogOut_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogOut.Click
    If logOut() Then
        Me.Dispose()
        frmLogIn.Show()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub frmHome_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    If logOut() Then
        Me.Dispose()
        frmLogIn.Show()
    Else
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub

Public Function logOut() As Boolean
    Dim respond = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to log out?", "Log Out", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
    If respond = DialogResult.Yes Then
        blnResult = True
    Else
        blnResult = False
    End If
    logOut = blnResult
End Function
```

So anyone could help?

Comment: When they click the button you explicitly ask, then you ask again when the form is closing.  Get rid of the messagebox - you are essentially asking if they meant to click the button they just clicked.  Its annoying

Comment: Your problem is caused by the call to Me.Dispose inside the click event. This call results in the raising of the FormClosing event handler and you ask again to confirm the logout. Just remove the code in the button click and replace it with a Me.Close. But I really agree with @Plutonix .  Don't ask to confirm the just made choice unless you have some unsaved data the user will loose if you close the form

Comment: @Plutonix I wanna make it like u wan either exit by clicking the logout button or the "x" closing icon on the right top of the application. However, there is a MUST to prompt out a message box to ask them before they leave.

Comment: @Steve I changed by still appear twice.

Comment: @Steve Ok. I get what your means and it work now. Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

In your logout button event click

```
If logOut() Then //first line
    Me.Dispose()//second line
    frmLogIn.Show()//third line
```

End If//fourth line

in your second line which is Me.Dispose, you disposing the form, in other term you CLOSING it. So that, Your form_close event will be trigger because you dispose your form. That's why the message box pop up twice.